# error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am implementing Entity Framework Code-First methodology in my project and got stuck in an issue.

> **Error Details:** 18,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Byte[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member
>   'status' in type 'IMS.DAL.Users_mast' is not compatible with
>   'SqlServer.binary[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=8000,FixedLength=True]'
>   of member 'status' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Users_mast'.

**My Code:**
User_mast.cs file contains:

```
[Column(TypeName = "binary")]
public byte status { get; set; } // Active | Inactive (1 | 0 ), where I want status column to be created as binary column in sql server.

public class context : DbContext
{
    public context()
        : base("name=sqlConn")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Users_mast> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

and finally,

```
    context obj = new context();

    public void add()
    {
        obj.Users.Add(new Users_mast() {user_fname="Agnib", user_lname="Pyne", user_email="a@gmail.com", user_mobile="9830972301", username="agnib", pwd="As1232", created_date=DateTime.Now, status=1 });
        obj.SaveChanges();
    }
```

On running, I am getting the above error. I can understand its due to the status field set as byte which is not getting mapped as binary.

Then what should I do to make the column in sql server as binary? Is there any list of mapping between sql server types and .net types specially in case of EF Code-First?

Any help is appreciated. Please help!!!

Comment: Why do you want to store a true/false value as a byte in code and binary in the database?? What is wrong with bool and bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your property to:

```
[Column(TypeName = "bit")]
public bool status { get; set; }
```

The native C# type `bool` is specifically created to store true and false values. The `bool` datatype maps to the SQL `bit` datatype.

The `binary` SQL datatype is meant to store binary data like files or images. If you want to map to a C# property you could use a `byte[]` datatype (array of bytes). In that case the code would look something like this:

```
[Column(TypeName = "binary")]
public byte[] status { get; set; }
```

Comment: Well, its definitely a helpful information. Actually, i want to store 1 or 0 in database. For that I could use int also, but I do not want to use int. If I use bit type, will it store value as true / false or 1 / 0?

Comment: Bit will store the value as 1 or 0. It is the smallest data type there is. It is literally one bit (on or off, which in binary is either 1 or 0)

Comment: In addition the byte you are using now consists out of 8 bits.

Comment: You should accept this as the answer, and reward Maurits his 25 rep

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all columns were set correctly, but Oracle Unmanaged Driver apparently doesn't always load into visual studio quite right.

I could get it to work *sometimes*, but it often failed after restarting my visual studio development machine. I experimented with combinations of rebuilding + reloading T4 templates and Re-compiling files in the solution (MVC5 + EF + AngularJS + Bundled Web optimization).
In the end, this turned out to be a more straight forward solution:

This:
[Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. | Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2398397)[^]

- (a) Open Visual Studio Help/About Microsoft Visual Studio and click
  OK button to exit the dialog box
- OR
- (b) Open the to-be-used connection in Server Explorer